# How to extend the length of session name in tmux?

Tags: tmux

When starting a session in tmux like this:

```
tmux new -s session-name
```

I get the name display that does not show full name(session-name):

```
[session-n
```

How to configure tmux to allow it to show the entire name of the session? At least, extend its length to an acceptable size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the maximum character length of each status line 'section' with `status-<position>-length`, so for your particular case, add:

```
set -g status-left-length 20 # could be any number
```

to your `.tmux.conf` and it will no longer be cut off.